# Do we need Api Key for Google GCM implementation

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Do we need the API Key that we get from Google Cloud Console for implementation of GCM?

If yes, where do we use it?

In my understanding, we get registration id when calling the method 
`gcm.register(SENDER_ID)` where
`SENDER_ID` is a project number you acquire from the API console.

Guide me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the API key in your server when you send GCM messages to your devices.

When you send a HTTP request to GCM HTTP connection server, your headers must include `Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY` or the request will fail.

> To send a message, the application server issues a POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.
>
> A message request is made of 2 parts: HTTP header and HTTP body.
>
> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> - Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
> - Content-Type: application/json for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.

[(Source)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)

Comment: So the API key and register id  is pass to  application server where my other web services are handled  ,

Comment: But where do I get YOUR_API_KEY from? The Google Developers Console only gives me (for my "service account") a key pair file and a JSON file. No API key to be found. Do I have to acquire the API key at runtime using my private key?

Comment: @AndrewArnott : it can be available in Developers Console